# Привести массив .txt файлов в годный для импорта состояние

Tags: c#, sql-server

Поставлена такая задача, **надо объединить .txt файлы таким образом, чтобы их можно было без труда импортировать в базу данных MS SQL Server.**
Я знаю как объединять содержимое нескольких файлов в один фрагмент, но не могу понять, как это сделать так, чтобы данные были распределены по столбцам, чтобы их можно было импортировать.
Вот пример, как выглядит ***один из 76 файлов***:

```
Id: 1
Name: Мурзич Дорофея Никодимовна
Home address: 394071 Россия, Воронеж, ул. Челюскинцев  58, кв. 31
Phone number: +7 (910) 611-79-31
Date of Birth: 13.01.1987
Email: Makikoob@meragor.com
Password: mg*7k+4rgn-YhlLGMFhO
Nikname: Makikoob
```

Все 76 файлов надо объединить таким образом, **чтобы они имели такой вид**:

```
ID;FirstName;LastName;Patronymic;HomeAddress;PhoneNumber;DateOfBirth;Email;Password;Nikname;
1;Мурзич;Дорофея;Никодимовна;394071 Россия, Вроноже, ул. Челюскинцев 58, кв. 31; +7 (910) 611-79-31;13.01.1987;Makikoob@meragor.com;mg*7k+4rgn-YhlLGMFhO;Mikaoob;
```

*Таких блокнот файлов, как уже сказал, около 100, надо сделать так, чтобы столбцы шли как показано на рисунке 2 - первой строкой, а дальше уже шли только данные разделенные точкой запятой.*

Comment: Да в батнике обработать, и вся недолга. Вот только точка с запятой в качестве разделителя - а ну как она где есть в значении? весело будет импортировать...

Comment: Слейте в один. Тупо `COPY x:\folder\*.txt y:\temp\all`. Потом загрузите в таблицу с 1 полем TEXT и полем IDENTITY. Потом запросом распарсите в рабочую таблицу.

Comment: Я бы показал пример, но  мне лень текст перепечатывать с картинки.

Comment: @aepot, да я вам на почту или куда угодно скину )

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, убрал

Comment: Дам подсказку - уберите скрины и вставьте текст текстом.

Comment: @aepot, готово!

Comment: Я надеюсь в тексте не реальные данные о реальном человеке, а вымышленные?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot, нет, данные вымышленные ) О да, разобрался. Ты лучший просто. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливаем NuGet пакет **CsvHelper** и добавляем директивы

```cs
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;
```

Берем вот такую упрощенную модель данных

```cs
public class DataItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Name("Home address")] // аттрибуты можете убрать, если вам нужно имя свойства, а не точно так, как в исходных файлах
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    [Name("Phone number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Name("Date of Birth")]
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Nikname { get; set; }
}
```

Берем файлы с исходными данными и кладем в папку `\files` относительно исполняемого файла (например внутри `bin\Debug`).

Тогда вот такой код

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DataItem> list = new List<DataItem>();
        foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles("files", "*.txt"))
        {
            string[] values = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x => x.Split(':', 2)[1].Trim()).ToArray();
            list.Add(new DataItem
            {
                Id = values[0],
                Name = values[1],
                HomeAddress = values[2],
                PhoneNumber = values[3],
                DateOfBirth = values[4],
                Email = values[5],
                Password = values[6],
                Nikname = values[7]
            });
        }
        CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";" };
        using (CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter("users.csv"), config))
        {
            writer.WriteHeader(typeof(DataItem));
            writer.NextRecord();
            list.ForEach(x => 
            { 
                writer.WriteRecord(x); 
                writer.NextRecord(); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Выдаст ровно тот результат в файле `users.csv`, который вам нужен.

P. S. у вас опечатка в слове "Nikname", должно быть "Nickname"