# C#. Json. Как получить из данных в формате .json .txt или .csv файл, с данными пригодными для импорта?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

## Такая задачка:

#### У нас есть .json [скачать файл тут](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o4e5OdCA5OjruDKaLpjUi8SsEY7jIMGU), необходимо привести данные в подобющий для импорта вид, чтобы произвести импорт данных в спроектированную Базу Данных...

***Данные приведены в следующем виде:***

```
[
  {
    "ФИО":"Северинов Даниил Левович",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"w7NH?8",
    "Логин":"Jena",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Артёмов Григорий Евлампиевич",
    "Категория":"вторая",
    "Пароль":"w7NH?8",
    "Логин":"Gaellan",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Безрукова Арина Юлиевна",
    "Категория":"первая",
    "Пароль":"VnewFY",
    "Логин":"Gianae",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Суйкин Ипполит Игоревич",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"SAQdnq",
    "Логин":"Dyannan",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Татаринцева Софья Мефодиевна",
    "Категория":"m3Xn04",
    "Пароль":"Leannish",
    "Логин":"teacher",
    "Роль":""
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Деревскова Регина Федотовна",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"x#wgQ?",
    "Логин":"Eckinfin",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Воропаева Алла Тихоновна",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"Ozx44W",
    "Логин":"Doryd",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Кутюков Тихон Аполлинариевич",
    "Категория":"первая",
    "Пароль":"YO60F$",
    "Логин":"Lian",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Волкова Дина Глебовна",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"",
    "Логин":"",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Меншиков Игорь Карлович",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"3v}Rsa",
    "Логин":"Ookyanne",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Сязи Изяслав Ипатович",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"bma|9@",
    "Логин":"Genedia",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Кемоклидзе Лиана Станиславовна",
    "Категория":"первая",
    "Пароль":"m3Xn04",
    "Логин":"Gari",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Задкова Тамара Емельяновна",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"2wj~#l",
    "Логин":"Pauland",
    "Роль":"teacher"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Адоратский Поликарп Вячеславович",
    "Категория":"первая",
    "Пароль":"vq7Ok9",
    "Логин":"Carleyna",
    "Роль":"administrator"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Фоменков Венедикт Саввевич",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"$lbwPo",
    "Логин":"Yeisha",
    "Роль":"administrator"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Лощилов Эдуард Захарович",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"bAg5%e",
    "Логин":"Vineva",
    "Роль":"administrator"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Путинцев Федор Казимирович",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"ZoqNdg",
    "Логин":"Ougalyne",
    "Роль":"administrator"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Закиров Эмиль Трофимович",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"~Uzl${",
    "Логин":"Ouidong",
    "Роль":"administrator"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Доронина Оксана Брониславовна",
    "Категория":"первая",
    "Пароль":"ST85n5",
    "Логин":"Xanna",
    "Роль":"administrator"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Вихорев Богдан Артемиевич",
    "Категория":"первая",
    "Пароль":"pIC7eB",
    "Логин":"Juliana",
    "Роль":"administrator"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Явлюхин Яков Михеевич",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"V}X#In",
    "Логин":"Javann",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Кайназаров Кондрат Ираклиевич",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"ZiPEA*",
    "Логин":"Wynd",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Меншиков Самсон Филиппович",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"iyVE7o",
    "Логин":"Hiqu",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Лясин Антип Мартьянович",
    "Категория":"первая",
    "Пароль":"}4oSNo",
    "Логин":"Ianashty",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Бальсунов Кир Святославович",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"Lr}ih}",
    "Логин":"Arsonne",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Федулова Эмилия Никитевна",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"RhW7v0",
    "Логин":"Merie",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Артемьев Прохор Платонович",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"IZn7Rm",
    "Логин":"Xenayet",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Бобрикова Инга Марковна",
    "Категория":"без категории",
    "Пароль":"~$Z1m9",
    "Логин":"Wles",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Якимова Валентина Брониславовна",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"#p~VS1",
    "Логин":"Feive",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  },
  {
    "ФИО":"Абакумова Жанна Георгиевна",
    "Категория":"высшая",
    "Пароль":"Mflw2%",
    "Логин":"Ebbien",
    "Роль":"methodist"
  }
]
```

***Из .json файла, надо сформировать .csv или .txt файл, данные должны иметь следующий вид:***

```
ID;FirstName;LastName;Password;Login;RoleID;
1;Даниил;Северинов;Левович;w7NH?8;Jena;teacher;
```

***Чтобы первой строкой шли названия столбцов, а дальше все данные.***

**Всё это нужно для приведения данных в нужный формат, для дальнейшего импорта в спроектированную Базу Данных**

*Заранее спасибо и простите, если вопрос не понятен. Уточните пожалуйста не понятные моменты в комментариях, я обязательно прочту и внесу изменения.*

Comment: А почему сразу нельзя JSON -> база? Ну ок, даже если надо в CSV, то вам ведь уже дали [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281929/220553) того, как работать с форматом, не уж то на его основе нельзя сделать JSON -> CSV? И опять же, где ваши попытки? Или вы сразу сюда пришли, чтобы решили за вас?

Comment: Читайте json в массив объектов и пишете его потом в csv. Как сделать второе вы уже в курсе, а как сделать первое, показано в прилинкованном ответе.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @EvgeniyZ. Зачем нужен промежуточный файл? Можно загрузить файл JSON прямо из файловой системы в базу данных SQL Server.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, попытки свои сейчас тоже покажу. Я пытался сделать по существующему образцу. Появились некоторые трудности при разбиении на столбцы, ошибку сейчас напишу. Почему json нельзя сразу в БД, проблема в том, что надо разбить их по разным столбцам. ФИО не должно попадать все в один столбец. Так же надо роль отредактировать, вывести в другую таблицу и указать тут ссылку на неё.

Comment: @aepot, пасиб, я сейчас попробую )